# Heirarchial Database with Time Tracking

Tags: python, time, hierarchy

*Working in Python/Django 1.8*

I have a problem along the following lines:

**Assembly Table**

```
|Part 
|Parent (FK to other Part)
```

i.e.:

```
Car
|--Tire
    |--Bolt A
    |--Bolt B
```

**Journey Table**

```
|Date
|Distance
```

**I want to be able to track the journeys made by every part in my assembly, such as how far a tire has traveled.** To do this, I created a table called `Part Actions` that stores the `installed_date` and `removal_date`.

```
|Part
|Parent
|Installed Date
|Removal Date
```

Here's the problem: How on do I query the total time for a (e.g.) bolt that could have been installed on one tire, removed and then installed on another car?

**Bolt Serial 135 History:**

```
|[date] Installed as part of tire 012 on Car XYZ
|[date] Removed as part of tire 012 on Car XYZ
|[date] Installed as part of tire 025 on Car XYZ
|[date] Removed individually due to damage.
```

I could log every sub-assembly change in Part Action for every change I will preform, but if I have 500 parts and I remove the engine, I fear I will clog up the database very quickly. Is there any other way around this? Should I decouple the hierarchy (i.e. assembly) from the time tracking element?

I've looked at both Django-MPTT and Django-Treebeard. Both seem to have the hierarchical structure but without the time element.

*Please also ask for clarification if I've been unclear before writing extensive answers :)*